# Make span element visible in ItemBound event of repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I got this in Repeater's item template

```
<span style="color: green;" id="TickMark" visible="false" runat="server">&radic;</span>
```

In ItemBound event intellisense is not detecting this ID "TickMark"

I need to make √ ie Square root symbol visible inside data bound

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the control like this :-

```
((HtmlControl)e.Item.FindControl("TickMark")).Visible = false;
```

it worked

Comment: Mark this one as answer then.